# Solr set Default search fields

Tags: search, solr

I have defined a few fields in schema.xml as indexed and stored.
I want to search using the q parameter all the those fields without specifing.
I saww in a tutorial that it is possible to search using q=myText .

How do I set default search fields (since DefaultSearchField in SchemaXML is deprecated)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the  **default** `solrconfig.xml` file that comes with Solr, you will see that the `/select` `requestHandler` is configured with the default search field as `<str name="df">name</str>` in the `<lst name="defaults"> </lst>` tag.

You can also mark which `requestHandler` do you want to be used by default using `default="true"`.

For more information have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml)

Comment: Thanks. I already looked into that. it comes with "text" column like this <str name="df">text</str> (version 4.3.0. line 803) and yet it shows result in "name"

Comment: No Problem. But in my comment I mention that it comes with "text" and not "name". And yet it searches over name out of the box. Please re-read the comment

Comment: In the default schema.xml file there is a field name (line 111) and text (line 154) and then there is a copyField that copies values from name into text (line 257). Now the search is defaulted on the field text which has the values from the field name as well. Therefore, though you think it is searching from the field name but it is actually searching from the field text.